# Jersey DELETE request with a query parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to create an HTTP endpoint to delete a property but I'd like to add some additional metadata about who is performing the delete. I have the following server side code in Jersey.

```
@DELETE
@Path("/properties/{property_id}?deleted_by={deleted_by}")
public Response deleteProperty(
    @PathParam("property_id") int propertyId,
    @QueryParam("deleted_by") String deletedBy)
{
    ...
}
```

However when I try to hit the endpoint with a url like `/properties/123?deleted_by=test` I get a 404. If I delete the query parameter everything works as intended. Does Jersey not support query parameters for `DELETE` or am I messing something up?

Comment: Make sure on the client side you are sending an http Delete request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to mention the query parameter in the path annotation. Just the following should be fine:

```
@DELETE
@Path("/properties/{property_id}")
public Response deleteProperty(
    @PathParam("property_id") int propertyId,
    @QueryParam("deleted_by") String deletedBy)
{
    ...
}
```

The [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2193) has an additional example.

Comment: Removing the query parameter from the path worked. Thanks!